# cd40106 Problems

Tags: schmitt-trigger

so im trying to make this simple oscillator using ic cd40106 without any succsess. it's the usual astable multivibrator configuration using a 9v pwr supply, 220k resistor and a 2.2uf capacitor, the output goes through a 100ohm resistor to a red LED. the problem is that when i hook up the power supply the LED lights up as if there is a direct current flowing through it and no oscillation occurrs, and when i unplug the power supply the the led seems to oscillate just fine. i know that the current comes from the filtering capacitor at vcc when i unplug the power.
so why when the power is hooked up i get dc current through the LED and oscillations when the power comes from the discharging capacitor? 
i grounded all of the unused inputs aswell. funny thing is that the exact same circuit worked just fine a couple of days ago.

Comment: Your load current is too high and LED R is too low and Vdc is too high, so reducing Vdc by unplugging it makes it draw less current to LED (Vdd-Vf)/R.

Comment: There is no "usual astable multivibrator configuration". Please show your circuit and power connections.

Comment: You should not load the output of your oscillator as it influences the feedback. Use another one of the six Schmitt-triggers in the 40106 as a driver for the LED, as they have a much higher input impedance.

Answer (score 1):

CD series CMOS has an output RdsOn ~>300 Ohms so the LED series R should be 1K otherwise Vout drops and then feedback fails to reach Vdd*1/3 then it fails to oscillate.  Even if not a Logic"0" it is low enough to sink current to keep LED ON but NOT oscillate where it must go below Vdd/3 and above 2/3 Vdd on the input.  So the load MUST BE > 3x the output resistance of driver.

> It is also "Supply-Dependant RdsOn" and 74HC series was designed with 50~75 ohms output resisance for 5V , while 74ALS series was designed with 25~22 Ohms. for  Vdd<=3.3V supplies.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1MO5N.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

DEBUG ACTION

- measure Vout, Measure Vin, fix problem.
- Next time think ahead about Source/load impedance ratio and "load regulation"

Comment: impedance ratio works everywhere